# How to access a user control in a masterpage from a content page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

Lets say that I have a header user control in a master page, and want to change a property of the user control depending on what content page is loaded inside of the master page.  How might I go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use two methods. The first is by using `Page.Master.FindControl('controlID')`. Then you can cast it to the type of your user control. The second method is by adding a `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="">` OR `<%@ MasterType TypeName=""%>` tag to your aspx page. In the `VirtualPath` add the virtual path to the master page, or the class in the `TypeName`. You can then access everything with intellisense.

Comment: The MasterType directive should use either VirtualPath, OR TypeName, but is unable to use both.

Comment: @Mike is correct and I've edited the answer to reflect his comment.

Answer (score 6):

first find the user control in the masterpage as below.Then find the control you need to access their property.

```
UserControl uch = Page.Master.FindControl("ucHeader1") as UserControl;
PlaceHolder phProxylist= ucHeader1.FindControl("phProxy") as PlaceHolder;
DropDownList ddlproxylist1 = ucHeader1.FindControl("ddlProxyList") as DropDownList;
phProxylist.Visible = false;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

There's one other method, and that's by making a public property on the master page that exposes the user control.

Answer (score 1):

Using a public property would work. In the content page's FormLoad method, you could do something like this (VB):

```
Dim myMaster as MyMasterPage = CType(Page.Master, MyMasterPage)
myMaster.MyUserControl.Text = "Hello!"
```

Comment: Using code-behind files is not a best practice. Here is attempts to get rid of them at all http://haacked.com/archive/2008/12/19/a-little-holiday-love-from-the-asp.net-mvc-team.aspx

Comment: How is it not a best practice? You're confusing ASP.NET webforms, which this question is about and ASP.NET MVC. This answer is perfectly suitable.