# ASP.Net : How to call a method from one web page with another web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web site that includes two pages. one of them shows my basket (basket.aspx) and the other shows the product(product.aspx). I want to update grid view in basket page when the users click on each products when they buy them.
I test this [solution](http://forums.asp.net/post/set/18/1362262/2823598) but this code doesn't work for me.

```
ASP.codebehind_files_default2_aspx page = new ASP.codebehind_files_default2_aspx();
```

after  ASP. a message VS just show the name of my page and global.asax.I was searching in Google and the other codes just say the name of the page and define a variable to calls its method, but in my website i can't do that.

So How can i do that? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you make the basket a user control it will become easier to handle than an iframe (which, without going into great detail is rather frowned upon). You can put the user control on the master page and you will be able to access the user control's methods (think add/remove item). As Pleun mentions, the basket data should be stored somewhere else and the basket user control will just be displaying that data.

Here is some information on user controls:

1. [User control shopping cart](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93639/Simple-Shopping-Cart-Basket-User-Control-using-ASP)
2. [Accessing a user control in a master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382358/how-to-access-a-user-control-in-a-masterpage-from-a-content-page)
3. [Overview of user controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reason . I have a question: If my basket (as user control) appears in another page can i call its method?(like fillGridView() or ...) ?

Comment: a user control is a user defined control so you drag and drop it on a page like a `gridview`, `radiobuttonlist`, etc. this means wherever you drop it you will have access to its methods.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it is a better idea to have the content of the basket stored somewhere else (Database, Session, file ).

Let's assume it s a database table.

- Make the Basket.aspx simply show all what is in the basket table from
  it's own codebehind.
- Make the Project.asxp  insert the product to the
  basket table.

This way your presentation is more separated from your business logic

Comment: thank you for your reason . i show basket.aspx in iframe in master page. i can show the whole basket when i put its grid view in update panel and refresh it in each 6 second, but i think it is better to update the grid view when new product add to basket . but i don't know how?