# accessing a user control from masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control in my master page under the login view  under the Role groups.Here is the  control.Its not in the content placeholder.However if i try to access it i get null result.How can i access this from my page code behind.I am having problem getting it from master page.

```
<asp:RoleGroup Roles="Students">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <uc1:studentsPanel runat="server" ID="studentcontrol" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                     </asp:RoleGroup>
```

Here is how i am having my code

```
LoginView control = Page.Master.FindControl("studentcontrol") as LoginView;
            if (control != null)
            {
                Label1.Text = "found";

            }
```

Comment: In what event are you trying to access this?

Comment: I don't think `Page.Master.FindControl` is the way to go. I could be wrong, but did you try `Page.FindControl`?

Comment: Am using it on page load.find control also returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code I use to get to controls in MasterPages

```
    //Master page from user control
    LoginControl control

    Page page = (Page)this.Page;
    MasterPage master = (MasterPage)page.Master;

    control= (LoginControl )master.FindControl("studentcontrol");

    if (control!= null)
    {
        Label1.Text = "found";
    }
```

Comment: Have used this code but i keep getting null   `LoginView control;

             Page page = (Page)this.Page;
             MasterPage master = (MasterPage)page.Master;

           control= (LoginView)master.FindControl("StudentsPanel");

                        if (control!= null)
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "found";
                        }`

Comment: If you watch the master, do you see your Contenttemplate

Comment: Yes.i can see the content template

Comment: Do you see the label inside the contenttemplate, if so change the part of find control, to look in the contenttemplate instead

Comment: In my content template have not used a label.the label i am using is on my page.could this be the reason?

Comment: You should then, once ou found the contenttemplate and your user control in it, look for the Label on your PAGE, then update it.

Comment: Please guide me on your statement.what do you mean by update label?

Comment: Update the Label with the data or text you wwant .. I aaume you got it though

Answer (score 0):

We can't see the whole code, but your snippets seem correct. Try first not to cast your control to LoginView - the reason might be that your panel is not of that type. To try out if the control is found at all, use

```
if(Page.Master.FindControl("studentcontrol") != null) {
    Label1.Text = "found";
}
```

first before adding another possible source of failure.

There's two more explicit answers that don't need to be repeated here. You find wonderful explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382358/how-to-access-a-user-control-in-a-masterpage-from-a-content-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240564/how-do-you-access-user-controls-on-a-masterpage-from-the-aspcontent-page-using/1240609#1240609).

Answer (score 0):

as @Krishnraj said,

i dont know which is control within studentsPanel UserControl, but i assume that Label. You should access like that,

```
var Loginview = (Master.FindControl("LoginView1") as LoginView);
Control cont = new Control();
Loginview.RoleGroups[0].ContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(cont);
(cont.Controls[1].FindControl("_trylbl") as Label).Text = "Hello say";
```

Comment: Hi,the studentsPanel is my user control

Comment: Hi,this means i should have a label in my content template?

Comment: No, only one example. You can put any control.